# "if cond1 or cond2" statement not running second condition in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

I am making a game in `Python` that looks like this so far:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random, threading
from threading import Timer
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
WINDOWHEIGHT = 720
WINDOWWIDTH = 1280
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hitman Grandma')
plorp = 'true'
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
cyan = (0,255,255)
windowSurface.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
hgleft = False
hgright = False
hgup = False
speed = 4
hgair = True
hgjumpallowed = False
level = 0
def stop() :
    hgbox.move_ip(0,0)
    return
hgbox = pygame.Rect(0 ,13 ,36 ,72)
hitmangrandma = pygame.image.load('hgrd1copy.jpg')
hg = pygame.transform.scale(hitmangrandma, (36,72))
landbox1 = pygame.Rect(0,400,200,50)
li = pygame.image.load('hgland1.png')
land1 = pygame.transform.scale(li,(200,50))
landbox2 = pygame.Rect(230,400,200,50)
land2 = pygame.transform.scale(li,(200,50))
land = landbox1,landbox2
while True:
    windowSurface.fill(white)
    windowSurface.blit(land1,landbox1)
    windowSurface.blit(land2,landbox2)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                hgright = False
                hgleft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                hgleft = False
                hgright = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                hgair = True
                hgup = True
                hgupkey = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE or K_q and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                exit
            if event.key == K_LEFT or K_a:
                hgleft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or K_d:
                hgright = False
    if hgup and hgbox.top > 0 and hgupkey == True and hgair == True and hgjumpallowed == True:
        hgbox.top -= 100
        hgair = True
    if hgleft and hgbox.left > 0:
        hgbox.left -= speed
    if hgright and hgbox.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
        hgbox.right += speed
    if not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2) and hgair == True:
        hgair = False
        hgbox.top += speed
        hgjumpallowed = False
    if hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or hgbox.colliderect(landbox2):
        hgjumpallowed = True
        stop()
    windowSurface.blit(hg, hgbox)
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)
```

However, when I run my script, `hgbox` doesn't detect collision with `landbox2`, and just keeps falling. I think this problem is due to it only running the first part of the if statement, and not checking the other parts. What should I do to make it detect other parts of the if statement?

Comment: If the first `x` is `True` the second expression is not evaluated in an `or` expression.

Comment: `if (not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2)) and hgair == True:` maybe? I'm not sure exactly what combination you're testing for.

Comment: I would use brackets to separate each condition and the or,and in your statement....Sometimes they are trouble otherwise

Comment: @AChampion how would I get the second expression to be evaluated?

Comment: `a, b = x, x; if a or b: ...`

Comment: Making my conditions variables does not work. Is there a way to split an if statement into two separate parts?

Comment: I'd like to see an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do not know if an MCVE would help in this case, because this is the problem.

Comment: Hopefully the full code isn't too big

Comment: Another way to give an MCVE is to just provide the values of `x` and what result you expect after the piece of code executes.
This has .png files and .mp3 files and one needs to take out a lot of the code to get to the underlying logic.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'll fix it right away.

Comment: Great, this is much better! I have edited my answer accordingly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an mcve I meant something like this (a minimal but complete example that we can copy, paste and run):

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

def stop() :
    hgbox.move_ip(0, 0)

hgbox = pygame.Rect(0 ,13 ,36 ,72)
landbox1 = pygame.Rect(0,400,200,50)
landbox2 = pygame.Rect(230,400,200,50)
hgair = True
hgjumpallowed = False
hgup = False
hgupkey = False
speed = 9

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                hgup = True
                hgbox.x += 50
                hgbox.y -= 90

    if hgup and hgbox.top > 0 and hgupkey == True and hgair == True and hgjumpallowed == True:
        hgbox.top -= 100
        hgair = True
    if not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2) and hgair == True:
        hgair = False
        hgbox.top += speed
        hgjumpallowed = False
    if hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or hgbox.colliderect(landbox2):
        hgjumpallowed = True
        stop()

    screen.fill(pygame.Color('gray12'))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (120, 70, 70), landbox1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (120, 70, 70), landbox2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (50, 70, 170), hgbox)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

---

**The problem is caused by this line:**

```
if not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2) and hgair == True:
```

It's evaluated as

```
if (not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1)) or (not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2) and hgair == True):
```

The second part would be always `False` in the example above. The `hgbox` always falls unless the first part of the condition is False as well `(not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1))`, that means it can only stand on the left platform.

Try to change it to:

```
if not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) and not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2):
    # Move downwards.
```

---

**Edit:** Here's a complete example to show you how I would write the movement and jump code. Use `x_speed` and `y_speed` to move the player every frame (also accelerate the `y_speed`) and in the event loop just set the speeds to the desired values. If the player touches a platform set him to the `.top` of the platform rect and `hgjumpallowed` to `True`.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.color import THECOLORS


pygame.init()

windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720), 0, 32)

pygame.display.update()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

hitmangrandma = pygame.Surface((36, 72))
hitmangrandma.fill((250, 160, 50))
hgbox = hitmangrandma.get_rect(topleft=(10, 10))

y_speed = 0
x_speed = 0
hgjumpallowed = False

land_img = pygame.Surface((200, 50))
land_img.fill((50, 100, 250))
land = pygame.Rect(0,400,200,50), pygame.Rect(230,400,200,50)

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # Quit game by pressing on the "x" button.
            done = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key in (K_LEFT, K_a):
                # Just set the x_speed and then move
                # the rect in the while loop each frame.
                x_speed = -4
            if event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_d):
                x_speed = 4
            if (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w) and hgjumpallowed:
                y_speed = -17
                hgjumpallowed = False
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE or K_q and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
                done = True
            if event.key in (K_LEFT, K_a):
                x_speed = 0
            if event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_d):
                x_speed = 0

    y_speed += 1  # Accelerate downwards.
    # Move the player.
    hgbox.x += x_speed
    hgbox.y += y_speed
    # Check if player is on ground and can jump.
    hgjumpallowed = False
    for box in land:
        if hgbox.colliderect(box):  # If player touches ground.
            hgjumpallowed = True
            hgbox.bottom = box.top
            y_speed = 0

    windowSurface.fill(THECOLORS['white'])
    for box in land:
        windowSurface.blit(land_img, box)
    windowSurface.blit(hitmangrandma, hgbox)
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)


pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

There also was a mistake in the event loop: `event.key == K_RIGHT or K_d` is always `True`, because it's evaluated as `(event.key == K_RIGHT) or (K_d)`  and `K_d` is a truthy value.

Comment: There's probably more that could be fixed, but you should post a complete example first (I'll give you an upvote for an mcve).

Comment: So post the whole thing?

Comment: The whole thing isn't a *minimal* example.

Comment: I'd like to see something like the short example in my answer, with the complete movement and drawing code. Then I could give you better advice on how to restructure the program.

Comment: I tried putting `if not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) and not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2) and hgair == True:` but it makes `hgbox` not fall and go down if I make it go up.

Comment: You have to remove `and hgair == True`. Do you want to see how I would write the movement code?

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that Python evaluates the logical operators in the right order, add ().

`if (not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2)) and hgair == True:`

This evaluates to True when there is no collision with either `landbox1` or with `landbox2`, and when `hgair == True`.

Comment: The problem is that I need to detect if `not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1)` or if `not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2)`

Comment: So you want to detect if ANY ONE of these are true ALONG WITH `hgair == True`?

Comment: Yes! That is what I want.

Comment: I would add brackets to make sure Python evaluates the conditions in the right order. I'll update my solution.

Comment: `if (not hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or not hgbox.colliderect(landbox2)) and hgair == True:
        hgair = False
        hgbox.top += speed
        hgjumpallowed = False
    if hgbox.colliderect(landbox1) or hgbox.colliderect(landbox2):
        hgjumpallowed = True
        stop()` is what I have, but now my sprite does not move properly.

Comment: Maybe I need to put an MCVE in.

Comment: Yes. Always put an MCVE in.

Comment: I took out keyboard inputs. `hgbox` does move on both the x and y axis. `landbox1` and `landbox2` are actually 200 pixels wide, and therefore `hgbox` is able to jump and touch `hgbox2`.

Comment: Okay, well, since you have changed the question, I don't know what to do with my solution. I'll try to revert it back to what I had originally suggested with the conditional operators.